# Missing ID field in Sharepoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

I've been asked to add some sort of unique field to a sharepoint list. Of course my response was that all sharepoint lists have a built in ID column. Would you like it added to the view? Yes please!
So, having done this a thousand times before, I went to edit the view to check the box next to the ID field... it's not there.
I go to Google and see posts about going to "add column - show hide columns - check ID" but it is not there either. I thought maybe someone had renamed the original ID column but there are no column types to indicate this has happened.

I am not sure if this makes a difference but this is a sharepoint site that lives behind a teams site. I access it through Teams by going to "open in sharepoint - site contents" and then locate the list.
Am I missing something?

Update: I looked at other lists and they have the ID column. So I thought there may be something "special about this list so I viewed the page source to get the ListTemplateID and it is an empty string "" not quite sure how this is possible or what is going on here!

Comment: Is this list created from browser (SharePoint UI) or via migration or using any programmatic technique?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge (not my site) it was created in the usual add an App way. I've asked them if it is possible it was created in any other way (waiting for the response)